# how to know which mysqli_fetch_assoc row is selected

Tags: php, mysql, database

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    if($row["STATUS"] == 0){
        $row["STATUS"] = "<font color=\"red\"><b>DEACTIVATED";
    } elseif($row["STATUS"] == 1){
        $row["STATUS"] = "<font color=\"green\"><b>ACTIVATED";
    }
echo "<tr class=\"ctr\"><td><a href=\"editmember.php\">".$row["ID"]."</a></td><td>".$row["FNAME"]." ".$row["MNAME"]." ".$row["LNAME"]."</td><td>".$row["SECTION"]."</td><td>".$row["STATUS"]."</td></tr>";
    $_SESSION["id"] = $row["ID"];
}
```

If I clicked on the id in $row["ID"], How can I get the value of $row["ID"] that is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By passing it in the querystring part of the url in the href attribute of the link:

```
"...<a href=\"editmember.php?id=".$row["ID"]."\">".$row["ID"]."</a>..."
```

In editmember.php $_GET['id'] will contain the clicked id.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I need